# How to tag message of photo on facebook on android

Tags: android, image, tagging

I can post photo and message to my wall.. But I want to tag message of photo. Not photo tagging. I dont want to tag photo..

I looked developer facebook page and there was message_tags but I couldnt see any sample and also I read something that has some kind of Bug...

here is my code to post picture&message to my wall

```
            String response= mFacebook.request("me");
            params.putByteArray("picture",imgData); 
            params.putString("message", message);                   
            response=  mFacebook.request("me/photos", params, "POST");
```

how can I add some id to tag friends on MESSAGE !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [photo_tag](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/) for this purpose.

You need to fetch details of `text` field using following query.

```
SELECT text FROM photo_tag WHERE pid ='$pid'
```

Comment: But I dont want to tag photo.. I just tag friends on message.. and I think that is not tagging people on message.. ? and I dont want to get any message.I just want to tag friends on message?

Comment: what do you mean by this "how can I add some id to tag friends on MESSAGE" ?

Comment: okay.. let met explain. look that photo.. [link](http://f1203.hizliresim.com/v/s/3sxlp.jpg) I marked my friend's name with a rectangle. He tagged on message of photo. but I didnt tag him on photo. I just write @ on message and I choosed his name and I choosed him and he tagged on message.. think it like a normal message tagging.

Comment: do you mean by replying same person ?

Comment: no replying.. I just want to tag friend on message. not send message..tagging means give his id link.. look at this photo please http://f1203.hizliresim.com/v/s/3sy95.jpg  I tagged a friend on message which has written blue color font ..and marked red rectangle name is Seyit Ali